Unity OnValidate() does not react
This method is supposed to be called for each change in the inspector. When the script is changed and thus reloaded, the method works perfectly: The position gets snapped and the console reacts. However, the method ignores any further changes in the inspector, for example dragging the game object having the script or changing values manually. What could be missing to make it react to changes?
public void OnValidate()
{
    UpdateCellPosition();
    Debug.Log("works");
}


From the Unity Scripting API:

Editor-only function that Unity calls when the script is loaded or a value changes in the Inspector.

OnValidate only ever reacts to changes within the script itself, not for changes to other component (like Transform, in your "moving the object around" example).
There currently isn't a callback for changes that occur outside of your own script. You could bodge an implementation with [ExecuteAlways] (slow, if you're doing complex things every frame!), or use an event such as EditorSceneManager.sceneSaving to run your OnValidate() manually before the scene saves.

Thanks for the answer. Isn't there an option with [ExecuteInEditMode]? I tried this earlier, combined with the Update() method. But just like [ExecuteAlways] by the way, there is simply no effect. I might lack some setting. But I could try with EditorSceneManager later indeed.

You might also have to mark the gameobject as dirty so Unity knows there was a modification: EditorUtility.SetDirty(gameObject);. Was there no effect as in it didn't save, or that Update wasn't called at all? (if you did a Debug.Log in Update, did it print?)

Also, [ExecuteAlways] is a rename of [ExecuteInEditMode] (with the edge-case of prefab mode taken care of...)

As for [ExecuteInEditMode] before Update(): neither Debug.Log nor snapping worked.

Ah, it should be applied to the class definition, not the function declaration
